# Is Cinelerra available on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, mac, video-editing

[Cinelerra](http://cinelerra.org/) is available for Linux, and from quick searches it seems to have at least been ported to Mac at one point.  I have looked in the Macports repos but don't see anything.  Is this available for Mac?  Guess I could crank up a VM and run there, but would be nice to have it native.

Comment: All I could find that doesn't yield a "404 Not found" response is a Port Request for a native MacOS version here:  https://trac.macports.org/ticket/22549

Comment: There is not a direct port that I could find. However, there are some good alternatives (open source ones as well). Check out [Cinelerra Alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/cinelerra/?platform=mac)